# How to see the Dependencies linked to Deliverables - Project Online

Tags: powerbi, ms-project

We are using MS Project Online and have a couple of Deliverables in each Project (50+ projects). We then use the Dependency function to link them and update.

Question: how can you write a report that shows you what Dependencies are linked to what Deliverables?

[Demonstrating the table showing Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rCvK.png)

Using the API in Power Bi I can see in the tables Projects and Deliverables the column Dependencies however, you can't expand this data.